# Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data and one of the columns contains a number stored as text.
When an application updates it, it writes `_BAK` + datetime stamp behind the number.

I'm now trying to clean up the database by deleting all records that have `_BAK` in the number column where the most recent one must not be deleted.

```
id     sitenummer                  
28376  1441_BAK20130213151952032    
28377  1441_BAK20130214142314705
```

In this case the line with ID 28376 is the oldest and must be removed.

I have created a query that should do just that:

```
;with sel1 AS (
select t1.ID,t1.sitenummer, CONVERT(BIGint,SUBSTRING(t1.sitenummer,CHARINDEX('_',t1.sitenummer,0)+4,50)) as Stamp1    
from vdfkraan as t1
where t1.sitenummer like '%_BAK%' and (SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING(t2.sitenummer,0,CHARINDEX('_',t2.sitenummer,0))) FROM vdfkraan as t2 
                                      where SUBSTRING(t1.sitenummer,0,CHARINDEX('_',t1.sitenummer,0))=SUBSTRING(t2.sitenummer,0,CHARINDEX('_',t2.sitenummer,0))) > 1
group by t1.id,t1.sitenummer)

, sel2 AS (
select t3.id, t3.sitenummer, t3.stamp1, 
      (select TOP(1) t4.stamp1 from sel1 as t4
        WHERE SUBSTRING(t4.sitenummer,0,CHARINDEX('_',t4.sitenummer,0)) =SUBSTRING(t3.sitenummer,0,CHARINDEX('_',t3.sitenummer,0))
        order by t3.Stamp1 DESC) AS stamp2 from sel1 as t3)

, sel3 AS (select id from sel2 where Stamp1=stamp2)

--delete FROM vdfkraan
--where id IN (SELECT t1.id FROM sel3 as t1)

--select * from sel2
```

If I uncomment the last line (select * from sel2), it produces the following table:

```
id     sitenummer                 stamp1             stamp2
28376  1441_BAK20130213151952032  20130213151952032  20130213151952032
28377  1441_BAK20130214142314705  20130214142314705  20130213151952032
```

Table `sel3` contains one record with one column `id = 28376`.

So that seems to work just as I want it.

Now I comment the select line and uncomment the Delete lines.

Now I get the following error:

> `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2`
>   `Error converting data type varchar to bigint.`

So without the delete lines, all is ok, no errors, but with it, I get this error.
I have checked the data, there should not be any problem.

What is going on here?

Comment: Try replacing the CTE with temp tables to pinpoint the place where the error occurs, CTE's are executed only when referenced.

Comment: Also, you should be doing `SELECT * FROM sel3` on your query to see the results, not from `sel2`

Comment: Are you sure that the number in front of the `_BAK` always has 4 digits? Because if there are records where it has less than 4, there is going to be error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT  v.ID
        , v.sitenummer
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(v.sitenummer, PATINDEX('%_BAK%', v.sitenummer) - 1) ORDER BY v.id DESC) num
INTO    #temp
FROM    vdfkraan v
WHERE   PATINDEX('%_BAK%', v.sitenummer) > 0

DELETE  vdfkraan
FROM    #temp t
JOIN    vdfkraan v ON v.id = t.id
AND     t.num <> 1

SELECT  *
FROM    vdfkraan
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ea18/1/0)**

Comment: You could do without a temporary table: `WITH ranked AS (/* your ROW_NUMBER() SELECT without INTO */) DELETE FROM ranked WHERE num <> 1`.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks, I know that but i did it with temp table because sometimes CTE's can slow things down, that might not be the case with OP's situation but I had used the temp table just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I converted it to CTE (if that means using WITH) because the application is used by more than one so in theory if two users would run this query just after each other the second user would get an error because the temp table would already exist. Still it's a major improvement of my very bad code from 4 years ago when I was even more a beginner then I am right now :-)

Comment: @Eric Yes, generally, the simpler the code is, the faster it runs (of course there are exemptions to this :). The problem that you encountered with temp tables seems rather strange since local temp tables are created per session, that is per connection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247177/are-temp-tables-in-sql-server-multiuser-safe, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cb941c63-3d11-44ce-934f-5cc7797d8204/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use grouping instead of window function:

```
SELECT  max(id), max(sitenummer)
FROM    vdfkraan
group by left(sitenummer,charindex('_BAK',sitenummer));
```